# How to append or concatenate 'n' numpy arrays?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, append, concatenation

I want to append 10 numpy arrays one after another. Is there any functions like

```
vm_all = np.concatenate(vm_1,vm_2,vm_3,vm_4,vm_5,vm_6,vm_7,vm_8,vm_9,vm_10)
```

or

```
cre_all = np.append(cre_1,cre_2,cre_3,cre_5,cre_6,cre_7,cre_8,cre_9,cre_10)
```

The problem with `append()` is that it takes at most 3 arguments. And `concatenate()` takes at most 2 arguments.

We can archive the target with `for` loop. But I would like to know whether any function  available for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
vm_all = np.concatenate((vm_1,vm_2,vm_3,vm_4,vm_5,vm_6,vm_7,vm_8,vm_9,vm_10))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [hstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)

```
import numpy as np
vm_all = np.hstack([vm_1,vm_2,vm_3,vm_4,vm_5,vm_6,vm_7,vm_8,vm_9,vm_10])
```

There is also [vstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) if you want to concatenate along the vertical axis.

[Concatenate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) works as well, but you have to give a sequence of your arrays.

```
import numpy as np
vm_all = np.concatenate([vm_1,vm_2,vm_3,vm_4,vm_5,vm_6,vm_7,vm_8,vm_9,vm_10])
```